# Get related Pills content according with clicked img in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Given the following scenario:

- Angular 1.7.2
- Bootstrap 3

I am having some issues after the user clicks on the img:

**WHAT I AM GETTING**

Clicking on any img, a related modal windows pops up with the right content

click IMG 1: all works fine

click IMG 2/3/4: pills are not working

Clicking on tabs of IMG'S MODAL 2/3/4 and then clicking on on IMG's 1 the 
pills are showing the content of last click from 2/3/4 related to IMG 1.

eg. if I click on IMG 4 - TAB 3 and then I click to IMG 1 I am getting the content of IMG 1 TAB 3 even if I am on TAB 1

**WHAT I DESIRE TO GET**

Clicking on any img, a related modal windows pops up with the right content and related specific `pills`

**ISSUE MIGHT COME FROM**

I assume that the described issue is coming from the `id` of the `pills` which remains the same on each modal.

**I don't want/can not use: angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal 
to solve the issue**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
function($scope){
 
 
 $scope.mainTitle = 'MEET THE TEAM',
 $scope.headLine = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
 $scope.teamSection = 'EXECUTIVE TEAM',
 
  
 $scope.modals = [
  {
   bio: "TAB 1",
   experience: "TAB 2",
   motto: "TAB 3"
  }
 ]; 
  
 
 $scope.teams = [
  {
  name : 'name1',
  role : 'role1',
  mainImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  roundImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  bio : 'bio text here1', 
  experience : 'experience text here1',
  author : 'some more text1',
  mobile: 'READ MORE'
 
  },
  
  {
  name : 'name2',
  role : 'role2',
  mainImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  roundImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  bio : 'bio text here1', 
  experience : 'experience text here2',
  author : 'some more text2',
  mobile: 'READ MORE'
  },
  {
  name : 'name3',
  role : 'role3',
  mainImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  roundImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  bio : 'bio text here1', 
  experience : 'experience text here3',
  author : 'some more text3',
  mobile: 'READ MORE'
  },
  {
  name : 'name4',
  role : 'role4',
  mainImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  roundImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  bio : 'bio text here1', 
  experience : 'experience text here4',
  author : 'some more text4',
  mobile: 'READ MORE'
  }
 ];
 
}]);
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  height: 100%;
}

.p0 {
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 150%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.flex-child-edge {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  border: 0.5 #e3e3e3 solid;
}

.flex-child-text {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #777777;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.flex-parent-second {
  height: 150px;
}

.person {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.person img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.name {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.role {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.line {
  width: 50px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.roundProfile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.roundProfile img {
  max-width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

hr {
  max-width: 30%;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.modal-content {
  background-image: url(../images/e.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e3e3e3;
  border: none;
}

.nav-pills>li.active>a,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
  background-color: #b04890;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 0 50px 50px;
}

.nav-pills {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.nav-pills>li {
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.tab-content p {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.author {
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.flex-parent {
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .red-more-mobile {
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
    padding: 5px 0;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
  }
  .container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .modal-body {
    padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  }
  .nav>li>a {
    display: inline;
    padding: 2px 5px;
  }
  .nav-pills>li {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  .name {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .role {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
  h2 {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .flex-parent {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .flex-parent-second {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.7.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--<script src="js/respond.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{ mainTitle }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ headLine }}</h2>



    <div class="flex-parent">
      <div class="flex-child-edge"></div>
      <div class="flex-child-text">
        <h3>{{ teamSection }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-child-edge"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-repeat="team in teams">

      <!-- PERSON 1 -->
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-sm-4 person">

        <img ng-src="{{ team.mainImage }}" class="img-responsive center-block fade" alt="{{team.alt}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#person{{$index}}" />
        <div class="red-more-mobile visible-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#person{{$index}}">{{team.mobile}}</div>
        <div class="name">{{ team.name }}</div>
        <div class="role">{{ team.role }}</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal -->

      <div class="modal " id="person{{$index}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="roundProfile row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img ng-src="{{ team.roundImage }}" class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="name">{{ team.name }}</div>
              <div class="role">{{ team.role }}</div>
              <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="modal in modals">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">{{modal.bio}}</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">{{modal.experience}}</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">{{modal.motto}}</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="home" class="tab-pane  in active">
                  <p ng-bind-html="team.bio"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane ">
                  <p>{{ team.experience }}</p>
                </div>
                <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane ">
                  <p>{{ team.motto }}<span class="author">{{ team.author }}</span></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- Modules -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  <!-- Controllers -->
  <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WHAT I HAVE DONE TO SOLVE IT:**

- Removed `ng-repeat="modal in modals"` from `modal-body`
- Tab's name has been hardcoded
- Used `...{{$index}}` as per  above `modal` and @Anees user suggestion

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
function($scope){
 
 
 $scope.mainTitle = 'MEET THE TEAM',
 $scope.headLine = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
 $scope.teamSection = 'EXECUTIVE TEAM',
 
  
 $scope.modals = [
  {
   bio: "TAB 1",
   experience: "TAB 2",
   motto: "TAB 3"
  }
 ]; 
  
 
 $scope.teams = [
  {
  name : 'name1',
  role : 'role1',
  mainImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  roundImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  bio : 'bio text here1', 
  experience : 'experience text here1',
  author : 'some more text1',
  mobile: 'READ MORE'
 
  },
  
  {
  name : 'name2',
  role : 'role2',
  mainImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  roundImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  bio : 'bio text here2', 
  experience : 'experience text here2',
  author : 'some more text2',
  mobile: 'READ MORE'
  },
  {
  name : 'name3',
  role : 'role3',
  mainImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  roundImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  bio : 'bio text here3', 
  experience : 'experience text here3',
  author : 'some more text3',
  mobile: 'READ MORE'
  },
  {
  name : 'name4',
  role : 'role4',
  mainImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  roundImage : 'https://www.m5hosting.com/wp-content/uploads/no-profile-img.gif',
  bio : 'bio text here4', 
  experience : 'experience text here4',
  author : 'some more text4',
  mobile: 'READ MORE'
  }
 ];
 
}]);
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  height: 100%;
}

.p0 {
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 150%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.flex-child-edge {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  border: 0.5 #e3e3e3 solid;
}

.flex-child-text {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #777777;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.flex-parent-second {
  height: 150px;
}

.person {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.person img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.name {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.role {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.line {
  width: 50px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.roundProfile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.roundProfile img {
  max-width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

hr {
  max-width: 30%;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.modal-content {
  background-image: url(../images/e.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e3e3e3;
  border: none;
}

.nav-pills>li.active>a,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
  background-color: #b04890;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 0 50px 50px;
}

.nav-pills {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.nav-pills>li {
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.tab-content p {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.author {
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.flex-parent {
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .red-more-mobile {
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
    padding: 5px 0;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
  }
  .container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .modal-body {
    padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  }
  .nav>li>a {
    display: inline;
    padding: 2px 5px;
  }
  .nav-pills>li {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  .name {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .role {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
  h2 {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .flex-parent {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .flex-parent-second {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.7.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--<script src="js/respond.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{ mainTitle }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ headLine }}</h2>



    <div class="flex-parent">
      <div class="flex-child-edge"></div>
      <div class="flex-child-text">
        <h3>{{ teamSection }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-child-edge"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-repeat="team in teams">

      <!-- PERSON 1 -->
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-sm-4 person">

        <img ng-src="{{ team.mainImage }}" class="img-responsive center-block fade" alt="{{team.alt}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#person{{$index}}" />
        <div class="red-more-mobile visible-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#person{{$index}}">{{team.mobile}}</div>
        <div class="name">{{ team.name }}</div>
        <div class="role">{{ team.role }}</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal -->

      <div class="modal " id="person{{$index}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="roundProfile row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img ng-src="{{ team.roundImage }}" class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="name">{{ team.name }}</div>
              <div class="role">{{ team.role }}</div>
              <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home{{$index}}">TAB 1</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1{{$index}}">TAB 2</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2{{$index}}">TAB 3</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="home{{$index}}" class="tab-pane in active">
                  <p ng-bind-html="team.bio"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="menu1{{$index}}" class="tab-pane ">
                  <p>{{ team.experience }}</p>
                </div>
                <div id="menu2{{$index}}" class="tab-pane ">
                  <p>{{ team.motto }}<span class="author">{{ team.author }}</span></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- Modules -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  <!-- Controllers -->
  <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

from your question, I assume , the modals are opening correctly but the pills are behaving indifferently. The reason for this is you have same id's for the tabs inside all the modals.

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane  in active">
    <p ng-bind-html="team.bio"></p>
  </div>
   <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane ">
     <p>{{ team.experience }}</p>
   </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane ">
  <p>{{ team.motto }}<span class="author">{{ team.author }}</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Changing the `ids` to something like `menu1_{{$index}}` and their links accordingly can fix your problem.
But ideally I think you should re-think the architecture for this to be some clean and maintainable code. I would suggest something like, keeping a single modal on the dom and dynamically load the contents you need, on click of any image.

Comment: I will definitely try to apply your suggestions. I'll keep you up to date. Thank you!

Comment: Just tried `menu1_{{$index}}` solution but it did not work. I will try to "re-think the architecture".
Do you think using `directives` could help?

Comment: have you updated the nav pills also accordingly ? `<li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1_{{index}}">` ?

Comment: Yup, but no luck :(

Comment: @Matt yes a directive would be better. But I would recommend https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal since you are using bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that too then, also I was thinking a `jQuery` solution making the `id` dynamic according with what has been clicked...

Comment: I have been able to solve it, changing part of the structure and using `...{{$index}}` as per your suggestion and as per my above modal. Thanks :)